# Undefined subtype 'subfigure' when using floatrow to create subfigures with subcaptions in VScode latex-workshop

Tags: pdftex, captions, floatrow, subfig, visual-studio-code

I am try to creat multi rows and columns subfigures each with subcaption. I've run my code in Overleaf, which works fine. However, when I run the same code locally on my windows laptop using VScode and the Latex-workshop extension, it goes wrong.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[][7.8cm]{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]{\caption{subfigure-a}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{E_track_erai_ubqb_cn1_ann}}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]{\caption{subfigure-b}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{E_track_erai_ubqb_cn1_ann}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{four subfigures}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the errors:

> Package caption: Undefined subtype `subfigure'. Line: 14
> which indicates the line above '\end{figure}'.

Any idea?

Many thanks,
Liang

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Don't load  `subfig`.  Load `caption` and `subcaption` instead.

Comment: Ok, changing caption and subcaption instead of subfig works. Thanks, @Bernard :)